# Parameter not received inside controller

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception

I try to send a parameter `applicationNo` wrapped inside my `form` tag.The data inside `input` generated via javascript snippet. I need to pass this data to my controller, but it always throw null pointer exception, I am not able to figure it out what is the problem.

So kindly suggest me the best way to achieve. I also attached required source code and snapshot.

I want to send the data highlighted in red area in below screenshot.

**JSP CODE:**

```
<form action="${baseURL}view_grp_conn_applications" id="grpCreationForm" method="post" commandName="command" >
                                    <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                                        <table id="addAppTable" class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped text-center" id="newField"> 
                                            <thead> 
                                                <tr> 
                                                    <th>#</th> 
                                                    <th>Application No.</th> 
                                                    <th>Name</th> 
                                                    <th>Mobile No.</th> 
                                                    <th>E-mail</th> 

                                                </tr> 
                                            </thead> 
                                            <tbody>
                                                <c:set var="i" value="0"></c:set>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="center"><input name="workOrderPostSps[${i}]" id="workOrderPostSps[${i}]" type="checkbox" value="${wo.woPostIdEnc}" onclick="highlightrow(this);" /></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><b><input  onkeypress="show_list('${i}');" id="appNo1${i}"  name="applicationNo" class="form-control start" autocomplete="off"  data-validate="required" required="true" placeholder="press  key on keyboard"/></b></td>
                                                    <td align="left"><span id="appName1${i}"></span></td>
                                                    <td align="left"><span id="appContact${i}"></span></td>
                                                    <td align="left"><span id="email1${i}"></span></td>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-turquoise  pull-right no-margin " name="saveBtn" id="saveBtn" value="Next >>" onclick="myfunction()">
                                    </div>               
                                </form>
```

**JAVA CODE:**
This method open the JSP from where I wish to send the `applicationNo`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create_group_connection")
        public ModelAndView createConnection(Model model) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/create_group_connection");
            Application application = new Application();
            mav.addObject("command", application);
            return mav;
        }
```

This method will open the jsp where i need to extract that `applicationNo`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/view_grp_conn_applications", method = RequestMethod.POST)
         public ModelAndView viewApplications(@ModelAttribute("command")Application application,HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/grp_conn_applications");
            try {
                System.out.println("inside view group applications");
                String[] applicationNo = request.getParameterValues("applicationNo");
               System.out.println("inside " + applicationNo[0]);
    //        for (int i = 0; application.length > 0; i++) {
    //            System.out.println("application number is" + application[i]);
    //        }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return mav;
        }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td><b><input  onkeypress="show_list('${i}');" id="appNo1${i}"  name="applicationNo" class="form-control start" autocomplete="off"  data-validate="required" required="true" placeholder="press  key on keyboard"/></b></td>


you just use the below instead of above

<input type='hidden' id="applicationNo" name="applicationNo" /></b></td>

you just set the application number using Javascript through id of  hidden field on  any event like onBlur, onKeyPress,Your Controller code is Correct
```

Comment: agreed, but i want to know why shouldn't i able to utilize the "name" attribute of input tag? why this isn't working?

Comment: Actually the Javascript function worked for id.  for name you need to write it enclosed with document.ready() with syntax like                       var x = document.getElementsByName("fname") due to this we prefer to use id

Comment: thank you amit for your quick response and valuable suggestions, it 50% solved my problem, now  this is not working in the dynamic row creation. Actually i wrote Js function which will generates the row dynamically, i append the hidden input field but now the value is not going to set inside hidden field. It only works for JSP hidden field.

Comment: if you need source code so pls let me know i will edit my question soon

Comment: Please provide code because JS not allowed hidden field

Comment: Hi Amit, the code is working fine without any issues thank you so much for your quick assistance, the problem occurred because of bad indentation.